# Authenticate with specific user in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to authenticate with a specific user that has access to pull down a package from a specific Azure Artifact Feed View using a Release Pipeline (which doesn't have the option of being fully YML) in Azure.

My workflow is to allow certain packages to be available via the @rc feed view and not always pull the latest package from the @local feed view since the @local feed view can have multiple packages that are dev builds which aren't ready for RC. I'm attempting to authenticate using an NPM Authenticate task but that doesn't give me the option to specify account details of a user that has isolated access to the @rc feed view.

I'm also not sure which user is actually being authenticated in the pipeline when that Release Pipeline task is run and according to the docs, it's the build user which isn't too clear.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

> I'm also not sure which user is actually being authenticated in the pipeline when that Release Pipeline task is run and according to the docs, it's the build user which isn't too clear.

The project build service account is actually being authenticated in the pipeline when that Release Pipeline task is run by default. You could get it from the `Feed settings`:

[image]

For you case, you could create a service connection with NPM Authenticate task for that  specific user with Username/Password or PAT:

[image]

[image]

And specify that specific user in the option **Specific people** when you create/edit the RC view：

[image]

**Note:** There are two important concepts to keep in mind:

- If a user have permission to a specific view, and even if they don't have permission to the feed, they will still be able to access and download packages through that view. If you want to completely hide your packages, you must restrict both feeds and views permissions. **To restrict access to your feed, simply select a user or group from the permission table in your Feed Settings and select Delete**. You can restrict access to a view by changing its visibility to specific people.
- views inherit their permissions from their parent feed. Setting view
  permissions to Specific people without specifying users or groups
  will cause the view permissions to default back to their parent feed
  permissions.

Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Comment: It's actually for an Artifact Feed that exists in the same org and not an external registry so using the NPM Authenticate task, I select the correct artifact feed from the drop down. The NPM Authenticate task doesn't allow me to specify the user or PAT. From what I've read, are those credentials required to be set directly in the `.npmrc`? They could be protected by being passed through as pipeline variables.

Comment: @strange_developer, the `.npmrc` file we specify in the npm authenticate task is used to specifies the registries you want to work with not the credentials. To resolve this issue, please try not use the default artifact feed from the drop down, try to create a service connection with specify the user or PAT.

Comment: I've created a user with minimal access, created a PAT for that user, given that user specific access to a rc Feed View (not full access to the feed), however, that user is still able to download the latest packages in the prod feed view. From what I've read, and the instructions that I followed in your answer, the user shouldn't be able to access any packages in the prod feed view but only in the rc feed view which is currently not happening. Not sure if I'm going wrong somewhere?

Comment: @strange_developer, Have you added this user to your org? If yes, try to remove it from your org. Create the PAT without give the permissions to read the Packaging

Comment: I created a PAT without any access to the Packaging. I've created a service connection with the PAT and it seems that the service connection is being used by looking at the usage history but getting packages from the prod view and not the rc view. 

If I login with the user I created and go to the Feed, I correctly only see rc view packages. Is this type of functionality supported in Azure or am I going about it the incorrect way?

Comment: I've removed all permissions from the feed entirely and managed to get a forbidden response. I proceeded to add the rc user to the feed and feed view without luck. I then added the Project Collection Build Service and that seemed to get the pipeline passing again without any forbidden issues. It seems although I'm using a Service Connection with specified credentials in npm Task,the Project Collection Build Service identity is used to download packages from a feed view. The Project Collection Build Service has Contributor permissions. Is it possible to use credentials specified in an NPM task?

Comment: @strange_developer, Sorry for the late reply, I just got out of other threads. Indeed, I agree with you. You can try to remove the group  Project Collection Build Service from the Permissions, then check if it works for you.